# AWS step function Parallel

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I'm trying out the AWS step function. What I'm trying to create.

1. Get a list of endpoints from the dynamoDB (`https://user:password@server1.com, https://user2:password@server2.com, etc..`)
2. From each domain, I get a list of ids. `/all`
3. For each id in the result, I want to do a series of REST etc `https://user:password@server1.com/device/{id}` (Only one request at the time to each domain in parallel)
4. Save the result in a dynamoDB and check if it is duplicated result or not.

I know how to make the rest call and saving to the dynamoDB etc.
But the problem or unable to find the answer to is.
How can I start run /all in parallel for each domain in the array I get from the dynamoDB?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/caolan/async? Specifically `async.each`.

Comment: pseudo code: [start function step] -> [Lambda function 1 gets domain list -> stores them to SQS] -> [PARALLEL: each Lambda function 2 gets one domain from SQS -> processes what you want with each domain] -> [end function step]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Step Functions have an immutable state. Once created, they cannot be changed. Given this fact, you cannot have a dynamic number of branches in your Parallel state.

To solve for this, you'll probably want to approach your design a little differently. Instead of solving this with a single Step Function, consider breaking it apart into two different state machines, as shown below.

## Step Function #1: Retrieve List of Endpoints

1. **Start**
2. **Task**: Retrieves list of endpoints from DynamoDB
3. **Task**: *For each* endpoint, invoke Step Function #2 and pass in endpoint
4. **End**

You could optionally combine states #2 and #3 to simplify the state machine and your task code.

## Step Function #2: Perform REST API Calls

1. **Start** - *takes a single endpoint as input state*
2. **Task**: Perform series of REST calls against endpoint
3. **Task**: Stores result in DynamoDB via Task state
4. **End**